# Jenkins "Choice Parameter" - is there any way to define text and value using separator?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

In Jenkins job configuration I can use list of values in "Choice Parameter" configuration - that's great.

I was wondering if there's any way to set text different to the value so value is a code and text is human readable.

Can't post images with reputation < 10, so here it is - https://i.stack.imgur.com/kx1lq.png

May be it's achievable using different plug-in, I would be happy to use it then. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a feature request outstanding for this https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/JENKINS-22317

Answer (score 2):

Inside Choice Parameter, no. But you can parse the value inside the build step with a scripting language of your choice...